# LibreOffice how to write the word "Size" in a formula/equation?

Tags: formula, libreoffice

Little thing has been driving me crazy... I have an equation with a variable called "Size" in it. Somehow, I cannot type it in my equation... If I type Size, the result is "??". I can type it such as: "Size", but then it appears like plain text, not italics. (my guess is that the parameter Size or size is used as something else in libreOffice and thus I cannot insert it as variable).

Any idea on how could I do it? What I'd like to have is this:

[image: -]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size` (with caps or not) is a reserved keyword. To get a word (like a variable name) of the same letters, put it in double quotation marks and make it italic:

```
italic "Size"
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I tried before but.. ehem... Had a typo on italic (I wrote italics instead of italic).. haha